# Reverse/flip the sides of two strings based on a delimiter?

Tags: r, string

say I have the following strings.

```
st = c( "50/90", "cat/dog,sheep", "08/25,000")
```

is there a function I can use to flip the order based on the "/" delimiter?

```
c("90/50", "dog,sheep/cat", "25,000/08" )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We could capture as a group (`(...)`) and reverse the backreference (`\\1`, `\\2`) order

```
sub("^([^/]+)/(.*)", "\\2/\\1", st)
[1] "90/50"         "dog,sheep/cat" "25,000/08"
```

Answer (score 3):

We can write one pretty easily:

```
st = c( "50/90", "cat/dog,sheep", "08/25,000")
strsplit(st, "/", fixed = TRUE) |>
  lapply(rev) |>
  sapply(paste, collapse = "/")
# [1] "90/50"         "dog,sheep/cat" "25,000/08"
```

Comment: Cool thanks; I was thinking about this but it felt like too many steps however did'nt realized you can just pipe it like that ```|>``` -- strange though I'm getting this error ```Error in match.fun(FUN) : argument "FUN" is missing, with no default```

Comment: The `|>` only works with R version 4.1 or greater, so you could write a nested version instead: `paste(rev(strsplit(st, "/", fixed = TRUE)), collapse = "/")`

Answer (score 3):

```
with(read.table(text=st, sep='/'), paste(V2, V1, sep='/'))

[1] "90/50"         "dog,sheep/cat" "25,000/08"
```

or even

```
do.call(paste, c(sep='/', rev(read.table(text=st, sep='/'))))

[1] "90/50"         "dog,sheep/cat" "25,000/08"
```